# finding the name of git branch from remote server

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, ssh

i am trying to find the name of git branch on remote server using a shell script. I put the following command in a script under the bin directory.

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

When I execute the script using `ssh` from another machine

```
ssh -i keyfile.pem user@ipaddress 'bash -s' /path/to/the/script
```

I get an error

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Not sure where I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `cd /path/to/your/git/repo` then `git branch --remote` to list the remote branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to git is using the wrong working directory (likely your home directory).

In your script, either cd to the path containing the git directory or specify the `-C` option with git:

```
git -C /path/to/git/checkout symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

The `-C` option allows you to overwrite the working directory:

> ```
>    -C <path>
>        Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working directory. When
>        multiple -C options are given, each subsequent non-absolute -C <path> is interpreted
>        relative to the preceding -C <path>.
> ```

Comment: YEP! adding the -c and the path option in the script worked! Thank you very much @Markus Kasten

Comment: Great to hear! Can close this question by selecting this answer as the accepted one if it was helpful to you?